# Proof of the lower bounds of time of algorithm working

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-science

I have asked this question on math.stackexchange already: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515920/lower-bounds-on-the-running-time

There are some problems, when there is non-trivial lower bound for working time of algorithm(that solve this problem): sorting, copying words on Turing machine...

What are the modern methods for proof lower bounds of time working do you know? Can you give a reference? Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking specifically about lower bounds on sorting, or about general lower bounds? If the latter, there are many questions on cstheory.stackexchange that answer your question...

Comment: This question is way too broad. Different lower bounds use different techniques.

Comment: "Lower bounds on the running time" is **not** a good title for a question here --- it is not sufficiently informative. I tried to improve the title, but you didn't like my idea, and rolled it back. Fair enough --- now **you** come up with a more informative title, please.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It is rather rare situation when we can find the greatest lower bound (and It is not trivial). I would be very grateful if you'll give examples.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek
About different - I think it is very cool to find general pattern

Answer (score 2):

Alexey, there is no general pattern that would work in many cases. If one could reliably compute a lower bound one would prove $P\neq NP$ just by computing the lower bound on any of the known $NP$-hard problems.

That said, the lower bound on sorting or $N$ possibly different elements can be computed rather easily by this method: compute the size of the configuration space of all possible solutions and take a logarithm. The reason why the result is **a** lower bound is that every algorithmic decision cuts the configuration space $S(N)$ of all possible solutions into two subspaces, and in order to cut down to one solution starting from the initial space of $|S(N)|$ possibilities on has to make $log(|S(N)|)$ decision.

In case of sorting the configuration space is all possible order of $N$ inputs, the size of which is $N!$, so the above method gives **a** lower bound $log(N!)$. Now use Stirling formula $N! \approx (N/e)^N\sqrt{2\pi N}$ to prove the lower bound $N\cdot log(N)$:

$log((N/e)^N\sqrt{2\pi N})=log((2^{log(N)\cdot N}\cdot e^{-N}\cdot\sqrt{2\pi} ) = N\cdot log(N) - O(N) \approx N\cdot log(N)$

Notice that the above bound is wrong when the number of diffrent elements is bound: the configuration space for sorting $N$ elements from $K=const$ possible choices is smaller than $N!$. This is why radix sort can be faster than the above bound.